# Integrate Django blog project in HTML website

Tags: python, django, html

I have a regular website where `HTML5`, `CSS3`, `JQUERY` and static images have been used.
I also have a Blog written in `Django` and I would like to integrate it in the website. 
I am really new to `Django` so I was wondering which is the best approach to use.
Should I integrate the website code as part of the `Django` project or there are some other solutions? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of integrating your current site with Django.

1) You can write `API` with `DjangoRestFramework` and make requests with `jQuery` `AJAX` in order to get content from Django.

2) You can use your current `HTML` files as your `Django` project templates for rendering content from `Django`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Django template. The template defines placeholders and various bits of basic logic (template tags) that regulate how the document should be displayed. Usually, templates are used for producing HTML, but Django templates are equally capable of generating any text-based format.
If you've used a templating engine like ''. They look somehow similar.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ordering notice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ordering notice</h1>
    <p>Dear {{ person_name }},</p>
    <p>Thanks for placing an order from {{ company }}. It's scheduled to ship on {{ s\
    hip_date|date:"F j, Y" }}.</p>
    <p>Here are the items you've ordered:</p>
    <ul>
        {% for item in item_list %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>{% end for %}
    </ul>
    {% if ordered_warranty %}
    <p>Your warranty information will be included in the packaging.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>
        You didn't order a warranty, so you're on your own when the products inevitably stop working.
    </p>
    {% endif %}
    <p>Sincerely,<br />{{ company }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

check here for more details https://djangobook.com/django-templates/